# Unable to run maven on pom.xml for my first spring app

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I created a small spring web app using [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) url. I downloaded the project and I am trying to run mvn package command under the folder where pom.xml resides. I am getting below error.

There is no settings.xml in my c:\LENOVO-PC\Users\lenovo.m2 folder. However I do have global settings.xml in F:\java\apache-maven-3.5.0\conf folder but all the entries in it are commented. Can anyone pls help me on this.

my contents of pom.xml are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**error details**

```
F:\demo\demo
λ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.1.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.1.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.196.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (F:\demo\demo\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.1.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.196.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: To supplement more details below is output of my mvn --version command                                                                                                               mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.5.0 Maven home: F:\java\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_162, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: F:\java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: It looks like you need to add proxy settings to your ~/.m2/settings.xml file. See [Using Proxies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove relativePath if you are using the standard layout.The error clearly states that the relative path points to no pom.Hence it is giving that error.

Comment: The error also clearly states that Maven was unable to connect to the central repository...

Comment: Then I guess he should add the proxy settings to settings.xml.

Comment: @Sr7 The relativePath in the pom is correct which forces maven to resolve that parent from a remove repository of from the local cache.. This does not work cause there are network issues.

Comment: Yeah @SteveC cleared it up for me.Anyway thanks man.Good to have more knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly the issue was different from what I thought. I commented the relativePath from the pom.xml however that did not help. Moreover than I disabled my Avast Antivirus which then resolved  this issue. Thanks everyone for providing your  inputs on this issue. Have a good weekend.

Sam